# isset( $_POST['submit'] ) is always returning false (I haven't forgotten name="submit")

Tags: php, html, forms

I've the following HTML form:

```
<form class="page-footer_enquiry-form" id="page-footer_enquiry-form" method="post" autocomplete="on" action="../php/enquiry.php">
    <h2 class="page-footer_enquiry-form-title">Enquiry</h2>
    <!-- Name -->
    <div class="page-footer_enquiry-form-name">
        <label for="footer-enquiry-name">
            <span class="page-footer_enquiry-form-label">Full Name</span>
            <input type="text" id="footer-enquiry-name" name="fullname">
        </label>
    </div>
    <!-- Email -->
    <div class="page-footer_enquiry-form-email">
        <label for="footer-enquiry-email">
            <span class="page-footer_enquiry-form-label">Email Address</span>
            <input type="email" id="footer-enquiry-email" name="email">
        </label>
    </div>
    <!-- Message -->
    <div class="page-footer_enquiry-form-message">
        <label for="footer-enquiry-message">
            <span class="page-footer_enquiry-form-label">Message</span>
            <textarea name="message" id="footer-enquiry-message" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
        </label>
    </div>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Message" class="button-dark">
    <p class="page-footer_enquiry-form-dialog"></p>
</form>
```

Which is "handled" by the following PHP:

```
if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){
    echo 'first';
} else {
    echo 'second';
};
```

Whenever I press the submit button, I'm getting 'second' (logged to the console via js).

EDIT - The jQuery:

```
handler : function(){
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../php/enquiry.php',
        data: $('#page-footer_enquiry-form').serialize() + "&js=true",
        success : function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
},
```

I fear it'll be something obvious to somebody else, but I just can't identify the problem. Help, please.

Comment: Might your request be redirecting by any chance or is something else happening to it via JS? Check your browser's developer tool's network tab and inspect the details of the request which is returning this error.

Comment: JS is added. @Fred-ii-: I'm definitely checking via a form submission.

Comment: try to debug your code. in PHP check what is coming from the form using `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: Do a `echo var_dump($_POST);` instead of 'second' and check the console.log

Comment: I am pretty sure your `submit` is not posting itself to server request because its not form redirect, its a ajax call

Comment: its working fine, put "echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST );echo '</pre>';" in your server and check you getting values or not and also submit value?

Comment: @AlexM: the following returns: array(4) {
  ["fullname"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["email"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["message"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["js"]=>
  string(4) "true"
}

Comment: it means your submit is not coming which is why "second" is printing.

Comment: if your using ajax you won't be posting the `submit` you'll be posting other data's only. Are you using ajax ?

Comment: @Raja: that makes sense - yes, I'm using AJAX. I wasn't aware that the submit event wasn't passed to PHP in this case.

Comment: @verism you can change your server code like this if(isset($_POST)) {...} to confirm request get.

Comment: @verism so while posting your question please make it clear :)

Comment: Use this to check for a POST request: `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')`

Comment: @Raja: fair point. That was certainly a novice oversight - apologies.

Comment: there is nothing to apologies. :) @verism

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a look at documentation of serialize() https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ you will find the following:

> No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button.

I think that causes your problem.